# How can I remove a class when the animation has ended?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, animation

Please help me with this problem.
I have a button called 'options' and if it is clicked, I want to add the class '.green' to it to start the animation. The animation makes the background of the button green and starts to fade it to its original color. However, if the animation is finished, I want the class to be removed automatically. This is necessary because if you add the class for a second time, it doesn't work anymore. I prefer NOT to use the 'timeout' function. I experienced a little trouble with it not to work every single time.

Below I posted a link to my code.

[My Code](http://plnkr.co/edit/v2SdFT4PPlY5MI4mTBxK?p=preview)

```
@keyframes correct {
  from { color:forestgreen; }
}

.green {
    -webkit-animation: correct 0.4s ease-out;
    -moz-animation: correct 0.4s ease-out;
}
```

Comment: suggest reading all the animation docs and looking at all the classes that get used within animation stages assuming you are doing this within the numerous directives that support animations. Then there is also `$animate` api

Answer (score 4):

You can listen for the `animationend` event on the element. [More in this article](http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-animation-javascript-event-handlers/).

Basically, assuming `button` is your button element:

```
var handler = function() {
    button.removeEventListener("animationend", handler, false);
    // (Remove the class here)
};
button.addEventListener("animationend", handler, false);
// (Add the class here)
```

(...or the Angular equivalent of `addEventListener`.) You may need vendor prefixes on that event name, details in the article.

I suspect you'll want to remove the handler (shown above), since of course removing the class will start another animation.

Comment: actually don't need this. angular ngAmimte module  already does all this internally with a number of different classes based on stages. Just a matter of using those classes in the css

Comment: @charlietfl: Even better! (That's an *answer*, not a comment.)

Comment: @charlietfl, I think you've got it mixed up actually.  AngularJS doc says this about angular animal: *if a CSS class is added to or removed from an element then an animation can be executed in between, before the CSS class addition or removal is finalized." However, OP want's to be notified of  end of animation, not when `.green` class is removed. As far as I know, AngularJS currently does not do this.

Comment: @IgweKalu there are multiple ways to do it including through directives that support animation internally as well as the whole `$animate` api

Comment: Actually, for example i want to be able to click 10 times on the options button and trigger the 'green' class every single time (with animations included of course).

Comment: @user1761155, have you checked my answer? With the approach I suggested, you should be able to do so any number of times you wish.

Comment: as per docs `ng-class` supports animations which means done properly you won't need any script ...just change model to trigger class and use the classes assigned internally by angular for stages in your css

Comment: @charlietfl, I don't think it can be done with `$animate`. But if you can, do prove me wrong by answering the question, I'd appreciate the opportunity to learn.

Comment: @IgweKalu no need..can just use `ng-class`

Comment: @charlietfl, as per `ng-class` supporting animation, check my answer.

Comment: @charlietfl: By far, the most useful thing to do here would be to demonstrate what you're talking about as an answer for the OP, rather than engaging in discussions about it. I stand ready to delete this answer if there's a solid Angular way to do it (and it sounds like there is) and I can see it in action. This answer is useless in that case.

Comment: @charlietfl, yes `ng-class` can do but it's not sufficient. Otherwise demonstrate how to do it for OP.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a reusable component that notifies animation end on an element as follows:

```
.directive("onAnimationEnd", ["$timeout", function($timeout){
  return {
    scope: {
      onAnimationEnd: "&"
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attributes){
      element.on("animationend", function(e){
        $timeout(funciton(){
          scope.onAnimationEnd({event: e});
        });
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

In your HTML, use the self-defined directive as well as `ng-class` and `ng-click` directives as follows:

```
<!-- the method `removeGreenClass` will be called at the end of animation -->
<button ng-class="{green: started}" ng-click="animationStarted = true" on-animation-end="removeGreenClass(event)">
```

Then define the `removeGreenClass` method by updating your controller as follows:

```
.controller("MainCtrl",function($scope){
  console.log("Main Controller says: Hello World");
    var home = this;
    home.opties = false;

    $scope.animationStarted = false; // initially false

    $scope.removeGreenClass = function(event){
        $scope.animationStarted = false;
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your answers, but also found an easier answer to solve the problem.
I used one line of jQuery to fix it:

```
$('#' + String(list.answers[list.x])).addClass('green').one('animationend', function(){$(this).removeClass('green')});
```

I just wanted to let you know..

Thanks!